# Handling State of React forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have 2 components - MasterList and DetailComponent

1. Clicking a value in MasterList sends data to input element in DetailComponent.
2. Detail component shows the prop passed
3. Detail component should be able to also update the input value

Step 1 and 2 are working , not able to understand how to deal with Step 3.

Following is the Sample code - [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qzj3jx3zw6)

Comment: Why put it in `componentDidUpdate`? Why not put the `store update` in the class method which could be called on click of a submit button?

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the form state with the props it receives. The input can be assigned the value of the state. Change in the input can change the state.

A submit button could be added which would take the state values to update the data. In this case you might want to remove the `componentDidUpdate` code and add it to your `handleSubmit` method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: props.user.username
    };
  }

handleSubmit = () => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    let payload = {
      username: this.state.username
    };

    dispatch(updateUser(payload));
  };

updateState = (key, value) => {
    this.setState({
      [key]: value
    });
};

<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={val => this.updateState("username", val)}
/>
```